# Is there a function on Keycloak that limits how many times one can make a request using an invalid token?

Tags: keycloak

We are using a Keycloak server for authentication and authorization.

Is there a function on Keycloak that limits how often one can make requests using invalid tokens?

For a security measure, lock the user after n number of retries.